# Database encoding change to UTF8 causing java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, sql, utf-8

I'm running a Tomcat WAR, which uses a MySQL database.
The application will run in foreign languages, so I had to change all database character parameters to utf8.

One application string (appPrefix) has to be empty (because the WAR is deployed in the root dir). This worked well, until I created a new database in UTF8 and migrated all the tables.

Now I get a NullPointerException because of the appPrefix being empty:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
com.horizon.servlet.PageServlet.doMainPageRequest(PageServlet.java:177)
com.horizon.servlet.PageServlet.doRequest(PageServlet.java:53)
com.horizon.servlet.PageServlet.doGet(PageServlet.java:33)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.horizon.filters.P3PFilter.doFilter(P3PFilter.java:19)
```

The above is all the same error causing ripples throughout the application.
It's all caused by appPrefix being empty, but it should..

Should I specify it as empty in another way? Or should I try to hardcode my way around this?

**EDIT:**
As per the request in the comment below, here is PageServlet.java:177

```
request.setAttribute("appPrefix", appManager.getAppStringById(11).getValue());
```

This references AppManager.java:

```
public static final int APP_STRING_APPLICATION_PREFIX = 11;
```

which is populated by

```
public AppString getAppStringById(int id) {
    AppString string = (AppString) stringCache.get(id);
    if (string == null) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM app_strings WHERE id = ?";
        List<Object> params = new LinkedList<Object>();
        params.add(id);
        string = execQueryLoadSingleRecord(query, params, new LoadAppString());
        if (string != null) {
            populateCache(stringCache, id, string);
        }
    }

    return string;
}
```

Comment: As with every other `RuntimeException`, this is just a bug in your own code. Please show the code behind `com.horizon.servlet.PageServlet.doMainPageRequest(PageServlet.java:177)`

Comment: So, `appManager.getAppStringById(11)` returned `null`? In other words, the `execQueryLoadSingleRecord()` method returned `null`? Why is it returning `null` then?

Comment: The database entry it's getting is empty, as it should.. So shouldn't it return null? Does this conflict with anything? The db string being empty was no problem until I changed the database's encoding to UTF8 from the default latin1 swedish!

Answer (score 1):

As per

> ```
> request.setAttribute("appPrefix", appManager.getAppStringById(11).getValue());
> ```

and

> *The database entry it's getting is empty, as it should.. So shouldn't it return null? Does this conflict with anything? The db string being empty was no problem until I changed the database's encoding to UTF8 from the default latin1 swedish!*

I understand that it's not a problem at all if `appManager.getAppStringById(11)` can possibly return `null`, right? In that case, you should check for it before calling `getValue()` on it.

```
AppString appString = appManager.getAppStringById(11);

if (appString != null) {
    request.setAttribute("appPrefix", appString.getValue());
}
```

As to why it returns `null` after you changed the table's charset; I have no idea. Perhaps it's just big coincidence or a misinterpretation of the problem. Perhaps you added `getValue()` call later on because you wanted to use `${appPrefix}` instead of `${appPrefix.value}` in EL or something. Or perhaps you rewrote `execQueryLoadSingleRecord()` that it returned `null` instead of empty string. Or perhaps the column's default value is `null` instead of an empty string. Or perhaps it's a bug in the JDBC driver used. Who knows. Using `null` as "no value" is perfectly fine and should be treated as such.